# soap php request with login in header

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am using SoapClient in PHP and I have a small issue with a small project.

I have the following `WSDL` that request usernae/Password in `SOAP` Headers:

https://www1.gsis.gr/webtax2/wsgsis/RgWsPublic/RgWsPublicPort?WSDL

The instructions says I have to pass username and password on Soap Header like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="http://gr/gsis/rgwspublic/RgWsPublic.wsdl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"> <env:Header> <ns1:Security> <ns1:UsernameToken> <ns1:Username>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:Username> <ns1:Password>YYYYYYYYYYY</ns1:Password> </ns1:UsernameToken> </ns1:Security> </env:Header>
<env:Body>
<ns:rgWsPublicVersionInfo/>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I use the following. I tried dozens of different approach but no luck!

```
$options = array ('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true, 'connection_timeout' => 5, 'Username' => 'XXXXXXX', 'Password' => 'XXXXXXX');
$client = new SoapClient("https://www1.gsis.gr/webtax2/wsgsis/RgWsPublic/RgWsPublicPort?WSDL",$options);
$params['afmCalledFor'] = 'XXXXXX';
$params['afmCalledBy'] = 'XXXXXX';
$result = $client->rgWsPublicAfmMethod($params);
print_r($result);
```

... and I always get the error `RG_WS_PUBLIC_TOKEN_USERNAME_NOT_DEFINED`

Thank you in advance for your help :).

Alex

After Denormalizer's help my code is like this (complete code):

```
$ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'; //Namespace of the WS.

//Body of the Soap Header.
$headerbody = array(
  'UsernameToken' => array(
    'Username' => '*******',
    'Password' => '*******'
  )
);

//Create Soap Header.
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'Security', $headerbody);

$options = array ('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true, 'connection_timeout' => 5);
$client = new SoapClient("https://www1.gsis.gr/webtax2/wsgsis/RgWsPublic/RgWsPublicPort?WSDL",$options);

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$params['afmCalledFor'] = '**********';
$params['afmCalledBy'] = '**********';
$result = $client->rgWsPublicAfmMethod($params);
print_r($result);
```

I keep getting RG_WS_PUBLIC_TOKEN_USERNAME_NOT_DEFINED (User calling service is not defined).

Any help is appreciated. I'm in chaos with this stuff.

Comment: You need to look into php soapheaders: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php

Comment: I looked into soapheaders but can't make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php#93460

```
$ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'; //Namespace of the WS.

//Body of the Soap Header. 
$headerbody = array(
  'UsernameToken' => array(
    'Username' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'Password' => 'YYYYYYYYYYY'
  )
);

//Create Soap Header.       
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'Security', $headerbody);       

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$result = $client->rgWsPublicAfmMethod($params);
```

Comment: I'm keep getting the same error RG_WS_PUBLIC_TOKEN_USERNAME_NOT_DEFINED.

I am copying the code from beginning to my original post. If you can help I owe you!! I'm going crazy with this stuff!

Comment: Looks like missing `mustUnderstand` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it myself, and I post it here in case someone else is wondering how to properly setup auth headers.

```
    $client = new SoapClient( "***WSDL_URL***",array('trace' => true,'exceptions' => true, 'connection_timeout' => 1) );
    $authHeader = new stdClass();
    $authHeader->UsernameToken->Username = "**USERNAME**";
    $authHeader->UsernameToken->Password = "**PASSWORD**";
    $Headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $authHeader,TRUE);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($Headers);
$options['**OPTION1**'] = XXXXX
$options['**OPTION2**'] = XXXXX
    $result = $client->***METHOD_TO_CALL***($options);
```